# How to install dual boot with windows on SSD and Ubuntu on a partition in the HDD?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I have a laptop configured with 128 gb SSD and 1 TB HDD with Windows 10 currently installed on the SSD. How do I install a Dual boot with Ubuntu so that it is only present on a small partition (say 100gb) in the HDD. I tried to do it but for some reason the system fails to recognize the presence of any OS other than Windows and before you say it, I did change the boot priority settings. If anyone has done it and/or can provide a detailed guide, it would be a big problem solved for me as I do not want to mess with the game library in my HDD.

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI mode? Ubuntu would have to be installed in the same mode as Windows.  Did you put an EFI partition on your HDD (so you could boot the device instead of selecting the Ubuntu OS)?  The Ubuntu install does not properly install anything to an EFI other than the one on the sda, but in that case, you should be able to select ubuntu from the EFI boot menu (some fct key at power up).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on the need for editing partitions in HDD and how to create them?

Comment: Any further advice depends upon the answers to the questions posed -- your Windows installation may very well be in legacy mode for all we know.

Comment: Windows installation is in UEFI surely. EFI partition exists only in SSD.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: 99% of W10 upgraded from W7 are still in legacy mode.  If your HDD is not going to be removed, you should be able to use the EFI menu to boot ubuntu, then change the EFI boot order with efibootmgr if you want ubuntu to be the default. Everything should be set up on the sdd's EFI, you just need to select it, not the HDD device, since it has no EFI partition anyway.

Comment: So, should I select the EFI partition on SSD to install grub bootloader and install the os files on the HDD partition?

Comment: Is "fastboot" in windows disabled? then make sure you have set aside 100G for ubuntu from your windows install. then use the strategy you just mentioned!

Comment: @George, yes I have disabled it along with secure boot.

Comment: Regardless of where you say to install the grub bootloader, it will go the the sdd's EFI.

Comment: @ubfan1 I did initially select the ssd for installing grub but it threw up a message saying "grub installation failed" and "this is a fatal error." So, I don't really know how.

Comment: Causes of grub install failures: 1)EFI runs out of room (but Ubuntu + Microsoft bootloaders only take 46M) 2)The EFI filesystem is damaged (try a filessystem (FAT) check) 3)Install mode is wrong, (legacy), and grub does not have a location to use for installation (a bios-grub flagged partition ) since it cannot slip between the partitions like on a DOS partitioned disk.

Comment: So my boot mode should always be set to UEFI in bios and never legacy?